# ThingWorx Azure IOT Hub connector not getting started

Tags: azure, azure-iot-hub, thingworx

I am using ThingWorx Azure IOT Hub Connector to connect the thingworx to azure Hub.

I am configuring the ThingWorx Azure IOT Hub Connector on a linux machine.

The configuration of my remote thingworx server in the conf file of the azure IOT Connector as follows:

```
 transport.websockets {
    // ThingWorx platform application key
    app-key = "app-key"

    // One or more platforms can be specified here, comma separated
    platforms = "remote thingworx url here"
}
```

and health-check also as follows :

```
health-check{
port =9009
}
```

Now when I run the azure-iot file from the terminal then I get no output on the terminal.

and when I try to send request to 9009 port in the browser then it is not working.

The error log I am getting is

```
Error injecting constructor, java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bootstrap 
required extensions; see log for details
at com.thingworx.connectionserver.PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.<init>
(PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.java:51)
at 
com.thingworx.connectionserver.PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.class
(PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.java:40)
while locating com.thingworx.connectionserver.PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl
at com.thingworx.connectionserver.ConnectionServerModule.configure
(ConnectionServerModule.java:47)
while locating com.thingworx.connectionserver.PlatformExtensionBootstrap
for the 4th parameter of com.thingworx.connectionserver.CXThingImpl.<init>(CXThingImpl.java:77)
at com.thingworx.connectionserver.CXThingImpl.class(CXThingImpl.java:47)
while locating com.thingworx.connectionserver.CXThingImpl
at 
com.thingworx.connectionserver.ConnectionServerModule.configure
(ConnectionServerModule.java:43)
 while locating com.thingworx.connectionserver.CXThing
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to bootstrap required 
extensions; see log for details
    at com.thingworx.connectionserver.PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.abort
  (PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.java:285)
     at com.thingworx.connectionserver.PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.queryInstalledExtensions(PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.java:190)
    at com.thingworx.connectionserver.PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.<init>(PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl.java:60)
    at com.thingworx.connectionserver.PlatformExtensionBootstrapImpl$$FastClassByGuice$$be072900.newInstance(<generated>)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$FastClassProxy.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:89)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.provision(ConstructorInjector.java:111)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:90)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:268)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get(InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:56)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter$1.call(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:46)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1092)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.get(ProviderToInternalFactoryAdapter.java:40)
    at com.google.inject.internal.SingletonScope$1.get(SingletonScope.java:194)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.get
  (InternalFactoryToProviderAdapter.java:41)
    at 
 com.google.inject.internal.SingleParameterInjector.inject
 (SingleParameterInjector.java:38)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I was able to resolve this issue.

The application key of Thingworx was incorrect.

I corrected the key and this error stopped coming.